# 'brew install yarn --ignore-dependencies' occur `brew doctor` warning

Tags: node.js, homebrew, yarnpkg, nvm

I ran: `brew install yarn --ignore-dependencies`

Installing yarn without node was successful.
But `brew doctor` showed a warning.

```
Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install node

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

I use `nodebrew` to manage node versions. And `yarn` command is running normally. So, I don't need to install another node.
Is there anyone who has same warning? and Can I solve this warning?

Comment: Sorry, I solved this warning. Create symbol link from `/usr/local/Cellar/node` to current node's global version.